# unexpected kENSURE, expecting $end - Rails/Cucumber/Haml

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber, haml

Been having a problem with Rails/Cucumber/Haml. The below Haml file works perfectly in the development and live environments but fails in Cucumber with the following error:

```
/app/views/competitions/show.haml:30: syntax error, unexpected kENSURE, expecting $end (ActionView::TemplateError)
On line #30 of app/views/competitions/show.haml
```

Line #30 is the end of the file. It works in Haml gem version 2.2.3 but not in later ones (I've tried 2.2.23, 2.2.22, 2.2.17)

```
- title @competition.name

%h1
  =h @competition.name

- if @competition.image?
  #main_image
    = image_tag(@competition.image_url)

= RedCloth.new(@competition.description).to_html

%h2
  =h @competition.question

%p 
  - if @competition.running?
    = link_to 'Enter competition', enter_path(:id => @competition.secret)
  - else
    = case @competition.state
      - when 'scheduled' then 'Competition has not opened'
      - when 'closed' then 'Competition closed'

if can? :update, @competition
  = link_to 'Edit', edit_competition_path(@competition)
  |

- if can? :show_stats, @competition
  = link_to 'View stats', competition_stats_path(@competition)
```

Any ideas what's happening?

Comment: Hard to tell what's happening without having the actual code in front of me. Try temporarily deleting blocks of code, one at a time, and see what effect that has. Start to narrow it down. For example try deleting everything under and including the `%p` block, then re-run the tests.

Comment: On line number 24, did you mean to escape `if can? :update, @competition` to be interpreted as ruby code by preceding it with a hyphen? `- if can? :update, @competition`.

Comment: any chance you have an `ensure..end` exception handling block just prior to this HAML file being called? Seems to me an `ensure` has been called without an appropriate `end`, and the HAML file just happens to be in the wrong place at the wrong time. The error might be unrelated to this file.

Comment: Beyond the issue noted by Stephen, that error is usually caused by an open-ended conditional. That is, a conditional like an if ("- if 1 == 1") that does not have anything indented underneath it to execute if it evaluates to true. If there's nothing underneath the conditional for HAML to work with, then it doesn't generate the "end" for the conditional. Check each of your conditional blocks to ensure that something is actually happening if/when they are true.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience with cucumber+haml, this sort of thing is most commonly caused by ambiguity in method calling and haml losing track of the scope in conditionals. Try wrapping parentheses around all your methods.

In the code you posted, the first `if` is also missing its `-`.

I'd also recommend trying putting the `when case` section into a helper as haml sometimes gets confused with things like that, especially as they are set with `-`.

Which version of Rails are you running?